# WordPress restore the whole website only with ftp

Tags: wordpress, restore

so this might be a long shot, but I have a copy of the whole ftp directory of my old wordpress site and I would like to restore it as it used to be. However, before getting rid of the hosting and everything, I forgot to backup the original database, so now I'm only left with ftp directory, but the wordpress stores its content and pages in the database. So I was just wondering if somehow I could get lucky and restore all the content and database with only the ftp files. I highly doubt myself that such an approach would be possible, however I am no pro with wordpress so maybe there's something I could still do. (The original database is gone forever). Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Unless you have a backup of the database in those files, your content is unfortunately gone.

Comment: If you don't have a backup of your database you're basically out of luck. As you said yourself, "wordpress (sic) stores its content and pages in the database". Try asking your hosting company if they can provide a sql dump of your database. If they can't then you'll have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not... unless you happen to be exceedingly lucky and have a backup plugin's cache in your **wp-content** folder and there's a `.sql` or `.sql.zip` file there by some miracle!

Answer (score 0):

You can get some view of the web by using this link http://www.cachedpages.com/
And you can work on those text content displayed also you already have the image in the **wp-content** folder and you can rebuild the site with minimal time frame considering starting from the scratch

Comment: This is better suited as a comment. It does not answer the OP's question, but it is a potential way for them to save time when they need to rebuild the site.